# Display List Items with different background colors in android

Tags: android

How can i display list items(ListView) with different colors in android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Array of integer values of the color you wants to display and the call the `setBackgroundColor()` method in your `getView()` or `bindView()` method of your Custom Adapter.

Refer this : [Creating a ListView with Alternating Colors in Android](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your custom adapter. For example, inherit a CursorAdapter and override the `getView` method, there you may get the particular layout for that row of item and set a custom background to it.

Comment: Do you have any example related to it ?

Comment: @Kartik: Refer: **[Creating a ListView with Alternating Colors in Android](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/)**