# Change text color of an item in list view?

Tags: android, list, colors, view, adapter

I have a list view of items, every item has a layout with three text views. I need to change an item's text views color, when the item is clicked. How can I get a link on this item and its views using adapter? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966128/display-list-items-with-different-background-colors-in-android/4966199#4966199)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you watched this great video from Google?
[Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Hope that helps.